# How do I get the slopes of an interpolation at regular time points on a cumulative sum plot?

Tags: r, interpolation, spline

Over at cross validated I asked a [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2686/104) about analyzing data by date but not wanting to generate spurious spikes and troughs by binning data by the month. For example if one pays a bill on the last day of each month but on one occasion one pays a few days late then the one month will reflect zero expense and the following month will reflect double the usual expense. All spurious junk.

One of the [answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/3060/104) to my question explained the concept of interpolation using linear spline smoothing on the cumulative sum to overcome hiccoughs in binning. I am intrigued by it and want to implement it in R but cannot find any examples online. I do not just want to print plots. I want to get the instantaneous slope at each and every time point (maybe each day) but that slope should be derived from a spline that inputs points from a few days (or perhaps a few weeks or a few months) before to a few days after the time point. In other words, at the end of the day **I want to get something such as a data frame in which one column is money per day** or patients per week but that is not subject to vagaries such as whether I paid a few days late or whether there happened to be 5 operative days in the month (as opposed to the usual 4).

Here is some simplified simulation and plotting to show what I am up against.

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
dates <- seq(as.Date("2010-02-01"), length=24, by="1 month") - 1
dates[5] <- dates[5]+3 #we are making one payment date that is 3 days late
dates#look how the payment date is the last day of every month except for
#2010-05 where it takes place on 2010-06-03 - naughty boy!
amounts <- rep(50,each=24)# pay $50 every month
register <- data.frame(dates,amounts)#this is the starting register or ledger
ggplot(data=register,aes(dates,amounts))+geom_point()#look carefully and you will see that 2010-05 has no dots in it and 2010-06 has two dots
register.by.month <- ddply(register,.(y=year(dates),month=month(dates)),summarise,month.tot=sum(amounts))#create a summary of totals by month but it lands up omiting a month in which nothing happened. Further badness is that it creates a new dataframe where one is not needed. Instead I created a new variable that allocates each date into a particular "zone" such as month or 
register$cutmonth <- as.Date(cut(register$dates, breaks = "month"))#until recently I did not know that the cut function can handle dates
table(register$cutmonth)#see how there are two payments in the month of 2010-06
#now lets look at what we paid each month. What is the total for each month
ggplot(register, aes(cutmonth, amounts))+ stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom = "bar")#that is the truth but it is a useless truth
```

[image: When one is late with a payment by a couple of days it appears as if the expense was zero in one month and double in the next. That is spurious]

```
#so lets use cummulated expense over time
register$cumamount <- cumsum(register$amounts)
cum <- ggplot(data=register,aes(dates,cumamount))+geom_point()
cum+stat_smooth()
```

[image: cumulative amount over time smooths out variability that changes an item's bin]

```
#That was for everything the same every month, now lets introduce a situation where there is a trend that in the second year the amounts start to go up, 
increase <- c(rep(1,each=12),seq(from=1.01,to=1.9,length.out=12))
amounts.up <- round(amounts*increase,digits=2)#this is the monthly amount with a growth of amount in each month of the second year
register <- cbind(register,amounts.up)#add the variable to the data frarme
register$cumamount.up <- cumsum(register$amounts.up) #work out th cumulative sum for the new scenario
ggplot(data=register,aes(x=dates))+
   geom_point(aes(y=amounts, colour="amounts",shape="amounts"))+
   geom_point(aes(y=amounts.up, colour="amounts.up",shape="amounts.up"))# the plot of amount by date
#I am now going to plot the cumulative amount over time but now that I have two scenarios it is easier to deal with the data frame in long format (melted) rather than wide format (casted)
#before I can melt, the reshape2 package unforutnately can't handle date class so will have to turn them int o characters and then back again.
register[,c("dates","cutmonth")] <- lapply(register[,c("dates","cutmonth")],as.character)
register.long <- melt.data.frame(register,measure.vars=c("amounts","amounts.up"))
register.long[,c("dates","cutmonth")] <- lapply(register.long[,c("dates","cutmonth")],as.Date)
ggplot(register.long, aes(cutmonth,value))+ stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom = "bar")+facet_grid(. ~ variable) #that is the truth but it is a useless truth, 
cum <- ggplot(data=register,aes(dates,cumamount))+geom_point()
#that is the truth but it is a useless truth. Furthermore it appears as if 2010-06 is similar to what is going on in 2011-12
#that is patently absurd. All that happened was that the 2010-05 payment was delayed by 3 days.
```

[image: two scenarios but showing the amount of money paid in each month]

```
#so lets use cummulated expense over time    
ggplot(data=register.long,aes(dates,c(cumamount,cumamount.up)))+geom_point() + scale_y_continuous(name='cumulative sum of amounts ($)')
```

[image: Here we see the cumulative sum data for the two scenarios]

So for the simple plot the variable interpolate.daily would be about $50/30.4 = $1.64 per day for every day of the year. For the second plot where the amount being paid every month starts to go up every month in the second year would be showing a daily rate of $1.64 per day for every day in the first year and for dates in the second year one would see daily rates gradually increasing from $1.64 per day to about $3.12 per day.

Thank you so much for reading this all the way to the end. You must have been as intrigued as I was!

Comment: I think you got bad advice - a more common statistical way to do this would be to use a kernel density estimate.

Comment: @hadley One of the respondents to my question [did talk about density estimates and kernels](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/2737/104). Alas I did not understand it much and he provided an implementation in matlab which I have never worked with.

Comment: Well it's trivial in ggplot2 - just use `geom = "density"`

Comment: @hadley So does that mean that one would do something such as this `cum <- ggplot(data=register,aes(dates,cumamount))+geom_point()` and then `cum+geom_density()`. But alas I get `Error in data.frame(list(x = c(14640, 14641.3679060665, 14642.7358121331,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 512, 1, 91` Anyway, even if I do use geom_density how would I get a data table of the new values per month or per day that are not messed up by binning?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one basic way to do it. Of course there are more complex options, and parameters to tweak, but this should be a good starting point.

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("2010-02-01"), length=24, by="1 month") - 1
dates[5] <- dates[5]+3
amounts <- rep(50,each=24)
increase <- c(rep(1,each=12),seq(from=1.01,to=1.9,length.out=12))
amounts.up <- round(amounts*increase,digits=2)

df = data.frame(dates=dates, cumamount.up=cumsum(amounts.up))

df.spline = splinefun(df$dates, df$cumamount.up)

newdates = seq(min(df$dates), max(df$dates), by=1)
money.per.day = df.spline(newdates, deriv=1)
```

If you plot it, you can see the interesting behavior of the splines:

```
plot(newdates, money.per.day, type='l')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. From the person who told me about this technique, I was advised that the cumulative sum would be monotonically increasing due to the non-negativity of the original values. That said I think the spline must be linear or set to monotonic. I will explore the splinefun funciton. But I am glad that you showed me how to throw a bunch of x's against the derived formula.

Comment: @Farrel Great I'm glad it helps. Definitely smart to explore the options like you said. The cumsum is indeed monotonically increasing (try `plot(df); lines(newdates, df.spline(newdates))` to see), but the first derivative that you wanted (i.e. money/day) is not. It will go up and down as you go from a long month to a short one, etc..

Comment: I am going to play with this tomorrow. Cannot wait

Comment: I do not know much about splines and I guess that deriv=1 is a calculus derivative and I also know little about calculus. Suffice it to say that the graph above is not correct because there is way too much fluctuation. Yes it will go up and down but by very little especially in the first year. So I tried forcing the splinefun `method="mono"` but every time I do that I get the following scenario `> money.per.day <-  register.spline(newdates, deriv=1)
Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied`

Comment: also FYI, Prof Hyndman has a monotonic spline function here: http://robjhyndman.com/software/monotonic-splines/